# aChartEngine Plots pushed off top off ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, achartengine

I've been struggling with this problem for awhile now. Basically, I've created a class that returns me a properly stylized GraphicalView chart; I have one class for bar charts and another for pie charts (I used renderer.setInScroll(true) BTW). I populate my Activity with a few charts and a few TextViews, but the more I add Views (any View) they are pushed off the top of the screen and there is a big empty space at the bottom of the scroll view.

My XML:

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollingProfilePaid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/paidLayoutLinearParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="00dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/GameTextWhite"
        />

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pastScoresChart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/GameTextWhite"
        />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalAverageResponseTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/GameTextWhite"
        />
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pastTimesChart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <!--...........-->
        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

What I've tried:

1.ScrollView->android:fillViewport="true"

2.Instead of specifying a height for the charts I set it in the java class using pastScoresChart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(dens*350)));

3.Wrapping the ScrollView in a , using a child Relative Layout with android:alignParentTop="true" as the header, another child Relative Layout with android:alignParentBottom="true" as the footer, and changing the ScrollView to android:alignBelow="@id/header". This just made the Scrollview about 40px tall, seemingly making the problem worse.

4.Oodles of other things that I can't recall this second.

I've found a workaround of setting android:marginTop="500dp" (or a similarly large value)  in the ScrollView will push the Views back down into their approximate respective positions. Unfortunately it is difficult to get it to fit exactly, and it worries me for device compatibliity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty space at the bottom of the `ScrollView` must be because of it's child (`LinearLayout`) attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"`. Try to use like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/paidLayoutLinearParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

**OBS 1**: The `android:layout_marginTop="00dp"` attribute is unnecessary. 
**OBS 2**: `fill_parent` is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`. So, use `match_parent`. 
More on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

**OBS 3**: Here is a tip about debugging layouts: change the background color of the views to see what are the bounds of each view.

Comment: MY GOD!!!! You're AMAZING! Thank you so much sir/ma'am, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Any idea why layout_gravity does such horrible things? And thanks for the other tips, that margin was there as it was a placeholder for my workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer yet but I'll try again once I get 15 rep.

Comment: You're welcome! `layout_gravity` is not horrible, actually is very useful. Just not on this situation (`ScrollView`). =)

Comment: Yes true. I was just trying to ask if you knew why Scrollview reacted in this way?